# Superset Parameters from dashboard to backend query

Tags: apache-superset

We have a scenario which is perfectly working fine in metabase but now we have to implement same logic and design in Apache Superset. We have to give a user ability to pass parameters to backend query in Superset which is pretty much simple in metabase but now we are struggling in Superset.

```
select 
customer_id,
(
select balance from  where cust_id = customer_id and date < {PARAMETER}
) previous balance,
current balance
from balancesheet 
where customer_id in {PARAMETER}
and date >= {PARAMETER} and date <= {PARAMETER}
```

Above is the requirement that we are trying to achieve in Superset but still could able to find the correct way.